# How to make non standard font applicable for IE browser?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

In my site i am using "TitilliumText14L" font using below code in css,

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'titilliumtext14l_400_wt';
src: url('fonts/titilliumtext14l_400_wt.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('fonts/titilliumtext14l_400_wt.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/titilliumtext14l_400_wt.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/titilliumtext14l_400_wt.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
#content{
font-family: 'titilliumtext14l_400_wt';
font-size: 1em;
```

}

But the problem is this font is working fine in all browsers except IE(all versions).
For more information i used " http://www.font2web.com/ " online font converter. To convert .ttf file to .eot file for IE.

Please let me know where i am going wrong. I got stuck in this problem. All suggestions and codes will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Font Squirrel - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Their font face generator produced headache free IE font styles and will even create the appropriate font files.